# Overstaying residence visa(work permit issued by UDI) in Norway by 1 day(5-6 hrs actually)

Tags: working-visas, norway, overstay, customs

I have been granted Trainee Work permit by UDI(Norwegian Directorate of Immigration). I applied for visa up till 11th July as my Employment Contract ends on 10th July. As for Norway, you get a temporary visa first, where end date of the permit is not mentioned so I didn't know that UDI has actually given me visa up until 10th July (as this date was mentioned in my employment contract). I booked return flight back home in the morning of 11th July.

I still have to go to police station to get residence card which would actually have VALID TILL written on it.

Ques 1. Can I tell police this problem and they might add another day to my permit end date? Do they have power? Or is there any other legal solution?

Ques 2. If nothing happens and I reach the airport on 10th July before midnight and talk to immigration office about my problem, would he/she allow me to check-in without any penalty as I would be able to check-in only after flight counter has opened and my luggage is checked-in?

Ques 3. If I do online check-in and do bag drop at self-service counters? How much early do self-service bag drop start? My flight is at 7:50 AM from Trondheim.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because I misunderstood your question. I think the answer to your question 1 is "yes" but I am not certain.

Answer (score 1):

If you come from a country that can enter the Schengen area visa-free, you could stay in Norway for up to 90 days past your expiration date. If not, read on.

1. No, unless you're prevented from leaving the country due to serious circumstances, such as illness
2. According to [Sleeping In Airports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/trondheim-airport.htm), Trondheim Airport closes overnight. So, no, they won't let you in that early.
3. Assuming you fly on [SAS](https://www.flysas.com/en/travel-info/check-in/online/), you can check-in your bags 22 hours in advance. However this won't help you in the case of Trondheim airport.

So the proper answer is: change your flight or book another one.